# Alignment in SunStudio C++ compiler

Tags: c++, c, memory-alignment, sunstudio

I need to declare type alias for 2 bytes variable aligned by 4 bytes.

In GCC, XL C/C++ (AIX), aCC (HP-UX)  I can use this code:

```
typedef uint16_t AlignedType __attribute__ ((aligned (4)));
```

In Windows I can use:

```
typedef __declspec(align(4)) unsigned __int16 AlignedType;
```

How can I declare same type in SunStudio C++ 11?

"pragma align" isn't suitable because it works only for global or static variable and It requires variable name.

Comment: Related, you can also use `__alignof__` to determine alignment for SunCC compilers. It is an extension like GCC's `__alignof__`. It tested good back to SunCC 5.8 on Solaris 9. Thanks to [OpenCSW](https://www.opencsw.org/) for providing access to their [compile farm](https://www.opencsw.org/extend-it/signup/to-upstream-maintainers/) to test old x86 and Sparc machines.

Answer (score 2):

As of Sun C 5.9 (Sun ONE Studio 12), the aligned attribute is supported:

```
typedef uint16_t AlignedType __attribute__ ((aligned (4)));
```

Unfortunately this attribute is not supported in C++ (at least through Sun C++ 5.10).

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth at least trying:

```
typedef union {
  uint16_t value;
  uint32_t _dummy;
} AlignedType;
```

This of course makes accessing a bit more painful, and kills direct assignment so it might break your entire code base. Also, it's purely based on the assumption that including a larger type, which is assumed to have "native alignment" of 32 bits due to being of that size, makes the `union` as a whole align on 32 bits.

Comment: It won't work. Variable must be aligned by 4 bytes, but size of variable must be 2 bytes!
For example size of st1 must be 8 bytes, but size of st2 must be 12 bytes.

struct st1
{
    uint32_t f1;
    AlignedType f3;
    int16_t f2;
};

struct st2
{
    uint32_t f1;
    AlignedType f3;
    AlignedType f2;
};

Answer (score 0):

For future references, when the compilers catch up, C++11 has standard alignment attributes, see `alignas` ([dcl.align] in [N3242](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf)).

Answer (score 0):

As of Sun C++ 5.12 SunOS_sparc 2011/11/16, the gcc syntax appears to be supported for C++ as per DRH's response:

```
typedef uint16_t AlignedType8 __attribute__ ((aligned (8)));
typedef uint16_t AlignedType4 __attribute__ ((aligned (4)));
typedef uint16_t AlignedType2 __attribute__ ((aligned (2)));
cout << __alignof__(AlignedType8) << ' ' << __alignof__(AlignedType4) << ' ' << __alignof__(AlignedType2) << endl;
```

The output is:

### 8 4 2